# Application launched using CreateProcess in windows CE doesnt show up in task manager as application

Tags: c++, windows-ce, createprocess, taskmanager, windows-mobile-6.1

I launch an application in windows CE 3.0 from a C++ dll using the CreateProcess() call. The application that is launched runs as per requirement. But this application is not listed in the task manager as an application. It is only seen when the settings of task manager is changed to show all processes.

How can i make the process launched appear as an application in task manager?

(I am using windows mobile 6.1, and the application to be launched is a c# .net CF application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To appear in the windows CE task manager the application must have a visible window. I use CreateProcess() to launch my C# app and it does appear in the task manager (I'm using windows CE 6.0):

```
STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 
    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
    siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 
    //start SQLServerApp
    if(CreateProcess(L"SQLServerApp.exe",0,0,0,false, 0, 0, 0, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo))
    {
```